# Pattern matching in R using grepl() function

Tags: r

I have below pattern match -

```
grepl("Close_[a-zA-Z]{0,}_{0,1}ASE_[a-zA-Z]{0,}_{0,1}", "Close_ASE_RS____")
#TRUE
```

R returns this as affirmative match. Shouldn't it be `FALSE` since I have `"____"` which has more than  `1` repetition of `"_"`, but in my pattern I put only max `1` match through `"_{0,1}"`

Any pointer why it is happening will be highly helpful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try indicating the string ends after your initial pattern:

```
grepl("Close_[a-zA-Z]{0,}_{0,1}ASE_[a-zA-Z]{0,}_{0,1}$", "Close_ASE_RS____")

# [1] FALSE
```

Otherwise you can put anything after the initial underscore following `RS` and it will match it.

Answer (score 1):

We can use word boundary

```
grepl("Close_[a-zA-Z]{0,}_{0,1}ASE_[a-zA-Z]{0,}_{0,1}\\b", "Close_ASE_RS____")
#[1] FALSE
```